# Using Jquery each() and children() to traverse and hide/focus form elements

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to write a simple script that emulates placeholders so that I can use the effect on all browsers. What I set up is a form with a span with some text in it that I absolutely position over the input. This acts like the placeholder text.

Now the Jquery is easy enough, and if I write out individual functions for each input element I get it to work fine, but that's kind of redundant. What I'm trying to do is use each() and children() and the classes so that I can apply this to any form I want. Here's the code:

```
<form id="signupForm" name="signupForm">
    <span class="inputSpan">
        <input value="" class="input" name="fistName" id="firstName" type="text" />
        <span class="inputText" id="inputText">First name</span>
    </span>
    <span class="inputSpan">
        <input value="" class="input" name="lastName" id="lastName" type="text" />
        <span class="inputText" id="inputText">Last name</span>
    </span>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.inputSpan').each(function() {
        $(this).children('.inputText').click(function(index) {
            $(this).children('.inputText').hide();
            $(this).children('.input').focus();
        });
    });
</script>
```

If I put an alert statement within the each function, it works, but it's not performing the rest of it which is to hide the child class '.inputText' and focus on the other child '.input' I'm guessing it has something to do with not being able to call $(this) again once inside a function. Anyone have any ideas on how I can get this to work?

**Solved!!! Thanks Matt**
Here's the final working code with the function to put placeholder text back in place if input is left blank.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('.inputSpan').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this)

        $(this).children('.inputText').click(function(index) {
            $input.children('.inputText').hide();
            $input.children('.input').focus();
        });
        $(this).children('.input').focusout( function() {
            if ($input.children('.input').attr('value') == '') {
                $input.children('.inputText').show();                   
            }   
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: @Jacob... using jQuery.each() is not needed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Untested, but I believe you're having a scope issue related to $(this)

```
$('.inputSpan').each(function() {
        var $input = $(this)

        $(this).children('.inputText').click(function(index) {
            //within this click handler, $(this) refers to the the '.inputText' not '.inputSpan'
            $input.children('.inputText').hide();
            $input.children('.input').focus();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking, that you can't call $(this) again once inside another function. I wasn't sure if something like this would work, but alas it did! Thanks a bunch!

Comment: This is a great work around for placeholders. Simple, clean, and easy solution if you're like me and absolutely hate labels!

Answer (score 1):

**Using your code...**

```
$(function() {
    $(".inputSpan").each(function() {
        $(this).children(".inputText").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
            $(this).siblings(".input").focus();
        });
    });
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hNXaF/

**A simpler way...**

```
$(function() { 
    $(".inputText").click(function() { 
        $(this).hide(); 
        $(this).siblings(".input").focus(); 
    });      
});
```

Here's a jsFiddle for this technique: http://jsfiddle.net/R6Vbb/

Comment: @JohnHartsock: Posted a simplified method

Answer (score 0):

Use `var $inputSpan = $(this);` to refer to the .inputspan

```
    $('.inputSpan').each(function() {
        var $inputSpan = $(this);
        $(this).children('.inputText').click(function(index) {
            $inputSpan.children('.inputText').hide();
            $inputSpan.children('.input').focus();
        });
    });
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to edit your answer. Meant to edit mine :)

Comment: OK Thanks @John Hartsock. I'll defer to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.inputSpan').each(function() {
var theInput = $(this);    
$(this).children('.inputText').click(function(index) {        
        $(this).children('.inputText').hide();
        $(this).children('.input').focus();
    });
});
</script>
```

The reason it was not working is because when you used '$(this)' inside of the click function you were referring to the inputText instead of the inputSpan.

See the jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/zachzurn/STmmP/

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use jQuery`.each()`.  It is not needed

```
$('span.inputSpan > span.inputText').click(function() {  
  var $this = $(this);  //for efficiency
  $this.hide();
  $this.siblings('input.input').focus();
});
```

In addition, it would be a good idea to use a tagname with the class selectors for efficiency.

Just using classname like this `$('.className')` causes an iteration of the entire DOM to find the element.  Using tagName in front like this `$('span.className')`  forces jQuery to make use of `document.getElementsByTagName` limiting the number of DOM elements to check.